# Grails RestfulController Overriding an resource update

Tags: database, rest, grails, save, overriding

So I'm having a little trouble when updating a resource in Grails. So here is my controller, in which I'm overriding some methods

```
@Override
protected saveResource(resource) {
    if (request.post) {
        permissionsService.addPermission(resource.id, springSecurityService.getCurrentUser(), 'Outing')
    }
    resource.save(flush: true)
}

@Override
protected updateResource(resource) {
    if (permissionsService.isAdmin()) {
        println 'doesnt print'
        saveResource(resource)
    } else if (permissionsService.canWrite('Outing', params.id, springSecurityService.getCurrentUser())) {
        println 'doesnt print'
        saveResource(resource)
    } else {
        println 'prints to console'
        response.status = 404
    }
}
```

This is what the top of the controller looks like

```
import grails.converters.JSON
import grails.rest.*

class OutingController extends RestfulController {

    static responseFormats = ['json']
    OutingController() {
         super(Outing)
    }
...............
}
```

My problem is that when I perform a PUT, for some reason the resource is still updated and saved. I can't figure out why because it never hits the saveResource or any other save function to my knowledge. I would like it to return with the status 404, but I could use some help with that. I'm basically adding permissions to the restful controller. Thanks for any help

Here is the RestfulController if you'd like to look. https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-plugin-rest/src/main/groovy/grails/rest/RestfulController.groovy